# Size Class для разных устройств iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, autolayout

Изначально проект был сверстан под **w**Any **h**Any, однако всё же возникла необходимость подшаманить верстку под iPad.

Означает ли это, что верстку необходимо полностью переделывать для всех различных видов устройств?

- iPhone Landscape: **w**Any **h**Compact
- iPhone Portrait: **w**Compact **h**Regular
- iPad Portrait/Landscape: **w**Regular **h**Regular

Или же достаточно дополнительно сверстать первые два пункта?

Answer (score 1):

Зачем переделывать вёрстку под iPhone, если нужно её переделать под iPad? 
Достаточно переделать только  для iPad, для iPhone будет браться из *Any*.